# how can i get the value selected in @Html.DropDownList in a MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code, how can I get the selected value of the  @htmlDropDownList to put this value in my @Url.Action instead of **1**, I have read using javascript o jquery but i cant figure out how can i do that in the view directly, and this is not working for my

```
var idempresa = $('IdEmpresa').val()
<a href="@Url.Action("List","Script")?idempresa=**idempresa**"
```

the code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Script</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdEmpresa, "Empresa")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdEmpresa", String.Empty )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdEmpresa)
        </div>
    </fieldset>


}


  href="@Url.Action("List","Script")?idempresa=**1**"
```

pd. thank you for the help

Edit:

```
  @using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model SistemaDispositivos.Models.Script

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Script";
}

<h2>Script</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Script</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdEmpresa, "Empresa")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdEmpresa", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdEmpresa)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url1 = '@Url.Action("List","Script")?idempresa=';
        $('IdEmpresa').change(function() {
            $urlId = $('urlid');
            $urlId.attr('href', url + $(this).val());
        });
    });

</script>


<a id="urlid" href="@Url.Action("List","Script")?idempresa=url1"> </a>
```

What iam missing?

Comment: What is your error? Can't tell you what's missing without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it work now this is what I wanted thank for the help:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Script</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdEmpresa, "Empresa")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("IdEmpresa", string.Empty  )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdEmpresa)
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function valid() {
        var listaScriptUrl = '@Url.Action("List", "Script", new { idempresa = 0})';
        var input = $('#IdEmpresa').val();
        $('#Lista-Script').load(listaScriptUrl.replace('0', input));
    }
</script>

 <input type="button" value="Click Here" onclick="valid()">

<div id="Lista-Script">

</div>
```

so now in the div Lista-Script when I click the button I get my view that I wanted

Answer (score 0):

The view would render HTML so you cannot get the selected value of dropdown list and put it back to the variable of the view which has already executed in the server side. What you could do is put an id on the  tag and update the href on change event of dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('IdEmpresa').change(function(){
         var val = $(this).val();
         var newurl = $("urlid").attr("href") + val;
         $("urlid").attr("href",newurl);
   });
});

<a id="urlid" href="@Url.Action("List","Script")?idempresa="> </a>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to account for the user changing the dropdown multiple times. That looks like it would simply keep appending values to where the second time you changed the dropdown, the url would be unusable.

Comment: Yeah. In that case the incomplete URL should be stored somewhere else and new value on href be populated every time on change.

Comment: it just have to change once the dropdow an click the link so the link will go to a view

i get and error went I do this, how can i create a onchange in this
@Html.DropDownList("IdEmpresa", String.Empty, new { onchange = "showTextBox(this)" })

Comment: you can create onchange using the above code, if u r using jQuery.

Comment: There's no need to attach the event directly to the DOM object.

Comment: i have edit the question what iam doing wrong? or what iam mising, i can't get in done

Comment: something wrong here, 

$urlId.attr('href', $urlId.attr('href') + $('this').val()); 

should be actually 

$urlId.attr('href', url  + $(this).val());

mccow002 wanted url variable to contain the incomplete url so that is what should be added to every time and 'this' should be without quotes to get the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this much like Bipins posted, with one major exception.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Script</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdEmpresa, "Empresa")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("IdEmpresa", *This needs to be a list of ListItems*, new { id = "idEmpresa" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdEmpresa)
    </div>
</fieldset>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("List","Script")?idempresa=';
    $('#idEmpresa').change(function()
    {
        $urlId = $('urlid');
        $urlId.attr('href', $urlId.attr('href') + $('this').val());
    }
});
```

By caching the original URL in a js variable, you always have a clean slate to append to.

Comment: What you just wrote looks fine.

Comment: i do not why is not working, a run the aplication select a item in the dropdownlist an it does not do anything :S
iam missing a using or somethin i just update my code above in the question

Comment: So you're saying that the href attribute doesn't change?

Comment: yes, as is in what I edited in the question it does not send me where I want, as is in what i edited does not show me a link neither

Comment: It was a stupid mistake on my part. You have to give the select list an id and use the # when selecting the element in jQuery. However, another thing I noticed - where is your IEnumerable of ListItems to actually populate the list?

Comment: i get then from my model, directly from my db, so that list me all the "empresas" I have
edit:
that is how scalffolding create it i just copy and paste and work jejej